# How to set category based on items in a group-by clause in Transact-sql?

Tags: t-sql, group-by, data-warehouse, user-defined-functions

I have a set of records that once grouped together I'd like assigned a category based on the combinations of records in that group..

Was wondering the best way to go about this..all I can think of is what I've got below but thought there may be a more clever way to do it (using UDFs maybe?)

```
SELECT *
, case when productgroup in ('chihuaha','labrador') then 1 else 0 end AS Dog
, case when productgroup in ('siamese', 'tabby') then 1 else 0 end  as Cat
INTO #tmp_items
FROM dbo.Items

SELECT docket
        , sum(value)
        , case when sum(Dog) > 0 and sum(Cat) > 0 then 'Dog and Cat' 
               when sum(Dog) > 0 and sum(Cat) = 0 then 'Dog Only'
               when sum(Dog) = 0 and sum(Cat) > 0 then 'Cat Only'
          end
          as Purchase_Type 
FROM #tmp_items
GROUP BY docket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to avoid that temp table etc is to perform the query in a very simple CTE:

```
WITH    tmp_items ( Docket, Value, Dog, Cat )
          AS ( SELECT   Docket ,
                        Value ,
                        CASE WHEN productgroup IN ( 'chihuaha', 'labrador' ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS Dog ,
                        CASE WHEN productgroup IN ( 'siamese', 'tabby' ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS Cat
               FROM     dbo.Items
             )
    SELECT  Docket ,
            SUM(Value) ,
            CASE WHEN SUM(Dog) > 0 AND SUM(Cat) > 0 THEN 'Dog and Cat'
                 WHEN SUM(Dog) > 0 AND SUM(Cat) = 0 THEN 'Dog Only'
                 WHEN SUM(Dog) = 0 AND SUM(Cat) > 0 THEN 'Cat Only'
            END AS Purchase_Type
    FROM    tmp_items
    GROUP BY docket
```

Might need some tweaking as you have not provided schema info & sample data but still - the fact you’re having to resort to this might suggest a problem with your schema. For instance, I'd usually like to see another table that defined Chihuahua and Labrador as dogs and Siamese and tabby as cats (2 new entities almost) rather than hard-coding these in your query - would be much better if they were joined in and then counted where not null etc.

Comment: This answer helped me write an aggregate select with left outer joins to lookup tables, thanks!